# OpenCart Manutenção Automático

Tags: opencart, automatização

Alguém sabe bastante de opencart?

preciso colocar uma loja em modo de manutenção automaticamente, no caso todos os sábados.
já personalizei a página de manutenção, só preciso deixar automático.

Answer (score 3):

É necessário utilizar o CronJob.

Sabendo disso podemos ir ao código.

```
<?php
class ControllerToolMaintenance extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        //Aqui o OC vai verificar se a key está correta, isso vai ajudar a fazer com que terceiros não faça esse processo manual.
        if (isset($this->request->get['key']) && $this->request->get['key'] = 'SUA_KEY') {
            //Aqui o código vai ativar o modo manutenção.
            $this->db->query('UPDATE ' . DB_PREFIX . 'setting SET config_maintenance = 1 WHERE key = "config_maintenance"');
        }
    }
    public function normal() {
        //Aqui o OC vai verificar se a key está correta, isso vai ajudar a fazer com que terceiros não faça esse processo manual.
        if (isset($this->request->get['key']) && $this->request->get['key'] = 'SUA_KEY') {
            //Aqui o código vai ativar o modo manutenção.
            $this->db->query('UPDATE ' . DB_PREFIX . 'setting SET config_maintenance = 0 WHERE key = "config_maintenance"');
        }
    }
}
```

Basta criar esse arquivo na pasta catalog/controller/tool e salvar como maintenance.php

Sobre o Cron: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/o-que-sao-e-como-usar-as-cron-jobs/